# CRUD : Adding Multiple Child Records (1-n relationships) on related CRUD form?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-backpack

Running: **Laravel 5.3** with **Laravel Backpack CRUD 3.1**

I am running into situations where I have a Model that I would like to add multiple related (child) records too, using just one CRUD form. Some examples would include adding multiple files... but let's start small. I have found the following posts that have similar topics, but not clear answer on the best way to do this.

Is the best way to use the `table` Field Type? https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/docs/crud-fields#section-table But, I guess the drawback is not having validation on the child records?

A similar tutorial to this one would be cool: https://backpackforlaravel.com/articles/tutorials/nested-resources-in-backpack-crud

So, an example would be where I have a **Journey** model and would like to add multiple **Chapters** to the Journey directly on the same Journey CRUD form.

Let me know if this question makes sense... and any suggestions/advice you can share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Backpack doesn't support adding more entities in one form - every such form is very different.

My recommendation would be to edit the `EntityCrudController::store()` and `EntityCrudController::update()` methods, to check for the values of the "table" field and add/update/remove connected entries.

Comment: at year 2021, is no a solution for this common use case? We cannot use table because it's using only text fields and we need a fw select2. Our use case is an 'event' havig child 'relations'.

Comment: This question and answer are from 2017. I think you should take a look at [our `repeatable` field type](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.1/crud-fields#repeatable-1) - I think it's exactly what you're looking for 

Comment: thanks, but no. In a lot of circumstances we need to edit related 1->N rows without using a simple json attribute.